# Does a cloud-docker private repo sleep like Heroku dynamo?

Tags: heroku, docker-cloud

I know that a free Heroku Dynamo sleeps after 30 minutes of inactivity. I can notice a significant start-up time for the first request.

Does the same apply to a free private repo on cloud.docker.com?
For my hobby project, which is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [classic private registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) should not sleep.

You have different hosting services for (one free) private registry: "[Comparing Four Hosted Docker Registries](http://rancher.com/comparing-four-hosted-docker-registries/)" (docker Hub, Quay.io, Artifactory, Google Cloud), and none appear to have that issue as well.